# Create a Joomla! Article Programmatically

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5

I have created my own component. When I add a new record to my component, I also want it to create a new article in joomla (i.e. using com_content).

I found this on stack overflow [Programmatically adding an article to Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041784/programmatically-adding-an-article-to-joomla) which explains how to do it. The code makes sense, and looks like it will work. The problem is that once methods start being called that are contained in com_content, all the relative URLs in com_content break down and joomla throws an error.

Does anyone know a way to overcome this? A comment from the link above suggests that changing the current working directory to the com_content one before including it will work, but I'm not 100% sure on how to do this.

Comment: What is the error that Joomla throws? Also, what version of Joomla?

Comment: I think PHP can't be more clear... the file does not exists.

Comment: Yes true, because the relative URL is not using the correct base path - thats my problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not possible to change the working directory because its a constant. To work around this issue you could choose not to use ContentModelArticle at all and instead use the table class only:

```php
$table = JTable::getInstance('Content', 'JTable', array());

$data = array(
    'catid' => 1,
    'title' => 'SOME TITLE',
    'introtext' => 'SOME TEXT',
    'fulltext' => 'SOME TEXT',
    'state' => 1,
);

// Bind data
if (!$table->bind($data))
{
    $this->setError($table->getError());
    return false;
}

// Check the data.
if (!$table->check())
{
    $this->setError($table->getError());
    return false;
}

// Store the data.
if (!$table->store())
{
    $this->setError($table->getError());
    return false;
}
```

Note that the code above does not trigger the before/after save events. If that is needed however, it should not be a problem to trigger those events. Also worth noticing is that the field **published_up** will not be automatically set and the articles within the category will not be reordered.

To reorder the category:

```php
 $table->reorder('catid = '.(int) $table->catid.' AND state >= 0');
```

Comment: $table = JTable::getInstance('Content', 'JTable', array());
didn't work for me in Joomla 2.5 but $table = JTable::getInstance('content', 'JTable');
worked.

Answer (score 1):

The error I get says:

> File not found /var/www/administrator/com_mynewcomponent/helpers/content.php

I got around the problem by creating an empty file at this location to suppress the error message and manually including `/var/www/administrator/com_content/helpers/content.php` with a `require_once` statement.

Answer (score 1):

#### Support Joomla 2.5 and Joomla 3.0

JTableContent is not autoloaded prior to Joomla! version 3.0, so it needs to included:

```
if (version_compare(JVERSION, '3.0', 'lt')) {
    JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_PLATFORM . 'joomla/database/table');        
}   
$article = JTable::getInstance('content');
$article->title            = 'This is my super cool title!';
$article->alias            = JFilterOutput::stringURLSafe('This is my super cool title!');
$article->introtext        = '<p>This is my super cool article!</p>';
$article->catid            = 9;
$article->created          = JFactory::getDate()->toSQL();
$article->created_by_alias = 'Super User';
$article->state            = 1;
$article->access           = 1;
$article->metadata         = '{"page_title":"","author":"","robots":""}';
$article->language         = '*';
 
// Check to make sure our data is valid, raise notice if it's not.

if (!$article->check()) {
    JError::raiseNotice(500, $article->getError());
 
    return FALSE;
}
 
// Now store the article, raise notice if it doesn't get stored.

if (!$article->store(TRUE)) {
    JError::raiseNotice(500, $article->getError());
 
    return FALSE;
}
```