# How to create an article with php in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a Jooma! Article Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643725/create-a-jooma-article-programatically)

I need to know, how can I create a new article in Joomla 2.5 with php code.

***EDIT***

**I found this:
[Create a Joomla! Article Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643725/create-a-jooma-article-programatically?lq=1)
it works in also joomla 2.5**

Comment: have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you only need to create a new article and in the textarea where you writte you have a botton "html" to insert you code inside you can put `<?php ?>` for your php code.

But I recomend you use a module or component for this.