# Create Joomla articles programmatically into multiple database table

Tags: mysql, joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I found this solution [Create a Joomla! Article Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643725/create-a-jooma-article-programatically)  very useful even with Joomla 3.1, however I ran into a new problem when, an editors-xtd plugin is enabled, that usually provides additional fields goes to database tables other than #_content. For instance, a tortags plugin would record tags to #_tortags table.

How do we pro programmatically update multiple tables in Joomla?

Answer (score 0):

Find you which fields of which tables you need to update and then update one table after the other. The example you linked to uses JTable to do the updates but you can also use the Database-object.
As an example, here's what I do to put an article (created by my code) to the frontpage:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$sql = "INSERT INTO #__content_frontpage (content_id,ordering) VALUES (" . $article->id . ",0)";
$db->setQuery($sql);  
$db->query();
```

Comment: I used to use this (and similar) approach, but the related tables, for instance, #__assets will not get processed, and it's trivial to write script to also update those tables. Advantage of getting an instance of either JTable or article model is you're effectively simulating the article submission process, hence all tables are updated after *validation*.

Comment: I don't think getting an instance of JTable would simulate the article submission, but using article model seems interesting - I could need that myself ;-)