# How to get article ID post article submission in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, article

I am able to create Joomla articles programatically. Thanks to the below post.
[Create a Joomla! Article Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643725/create-a-joomla-article-programatically)

The article is created successfully but now I want to capture the article id or the article url of the newly created Joomla article.

The idea is that once a registered user creates an article, the user will receive an email with the complete URL of the article that he/she has created.

-If the article ID can be fetched out, I can use index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=XXX
OR
- If the complete SEF URL can be fetched out then it will be great

snippet of the code is as follows

```
else {
        $table = JTable::getInstance('Content', 'JTable', array());
        $data = array(
            'catid' => $category,
            'title' => $msgbody,
            'fulltext' => $button,
            'publish_down' => $sixdate,
            'state' => 1,
            'metakey' => $meta,
            'metadesc' => $msgbody,
            'ips' => $ip,
        );

        if (!$table->bind($data))
        {
            $this->setError($table->getError());
            return false;
        }

        if (!$table->check())
        {
            $this->setError($table->getError());
            return false;
        }

        if (!$table->store())
        {
            $this->setError($table->getError());
            return false;
        }

        $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
        $config = JFactory::getConfig();
        $sender = array( 
            $config->getValue( 'config.mailfrom' ),
            $config->getValue( 'config.fromname' ) );

        $mailer->setSender($sender);

        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $urecipient = $user->email;

        $mailer->addRecipient($urecipient);
```

Comment: Try $table->id, after you store table with $table->store();

Comment: if (!$table->store())
{
 $this->setError($table->getError());
 return false;

This returns JTableContent. I am new to programming. I know this is not the correct way.
   
$table->id;
echo $table;

Comment: Happy I could help, don't forget to vote up my answer and check it as answered below :)

Answer (score 0):

From what i see in code, you can access article id after storing by using `$table->id` (after using `$table->store();` method);

The easiest way to build sef URL is to use native article route builder:

```
require_once(JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_content/helpers/route.php');
$link = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($table->id, $table->catid);
```

($table->catid param is optional)